# how can i return values from server request to the main page and use them as variables

Tags: php

login.php

```
<?php

  //get post data
  $user = trim($_POST['user']);
  $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);
  $nume = $_POST['nume'];
  $class = $_POST['class'];

  // Here I connect to the database and search for $user 
  // if $user is found, i want to:

          alert("succes");   // optional, just a reasurance 
          $name =; // the name of the $user in database
          $class =; // the class of the $user in database 

          // here i want to return the information that i need for main page
          echo $name;
          echo $class;

  ?>
```

a.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function checkForm(){
            var name = document.forms[0].user.value;
            if (name.length < 3) {
               alert("Username is too short");
               return false;
            } 
            else {  
               return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="login.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
            User: <input type="text" name="user"/>
            Password: <input type="password" name="pass"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="nume"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="class"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
       </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

How do I store the return values from login.php in two variables that i need to further change my main page? 
For example how can I have in the main page X = $nume and y = $class with values from login.php?

Comment: sorry. without $_SESSION

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['name'])) {`    none of your form inputs are named `name`   so this condition will always be false.  Remember javascript is client side. Try `if(isset($_POST['user'])) {`

Comment: yes i know, please ignore the syntax error, as it was not related to the question. i modified it anyway. my bet is with AJAX or JQuery with a callback function, but the return of the login.php is a text and I don't know how can i assign it to each value in main page?

Comment: Unless you use AJAX, submitting the form reloads the page. You can store values in hidden inputs on the new page, or you can set a cookie.

Comment: i have hidden inputs, in them i want to store the values

Comment: No offense, but there seems to be a lack of understanding about forms, variables and database results. Suggest you start here and read up a bit. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp    also, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp for using a database via mysqli

Comment: there is no offence. i'm new to this, and that is my problem. i can't understand how to pass variables from a php page to another. how to pass it I understand, but how to send another variables back is my problem :)